# How to anti-alias a collada model in papervision3D?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, papervision3d, collada

**How to anti-alias a collada model in papervision3D?**

I've tried searching everywhere but didn't find any ways to anti-alias models. I've also tried blurring it a little as an anti-alias method but that only f-s it up and makes it look worse.

How do I do that properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well , I've figured that out already

```
daeFile.getMaterialByName("Material_1").smooth = true;
```